# How to measure speed without any mechanical or electrical connection?

Tags: sensor, wireless, measurement, speed, frequency-measurement

I would like to build an as-much-portable device for measuring the speed of a vehicle, to check speedometer accuracy and know the offset if one present. The idea is a cigarette pack sized box one can take with when test driving a car, for example. This is nothing to do with very high accuracy or racing speeds.

My first ideas range from very a very basic, but very tricky to mount, contraption with some sort of switch that revolves on a wheel, and those revolutions per second are factored with the wheel diameter, to get speed. This metric would be communicated via radio or IR to the display unit.

At the other end of the complexity scale is an accelerometer, no mounting, no wireless connection, but the circuitry would be a good deal more complex.

Is there any other way of doing this.

Comment: I am usually fine with the accuracy of GPS

Comment: You haven't stated what accuracy/precision you require.

Comment: An accelerometer won't measure speed, only acceleration.

Comment: Re wheel measurements, as you increase speed, tyre rpm increases and the effective outer diameter increases - how would you factor this in?

Comment: Also re wheel measurements, as you turn corners your wheels move at different speeds. Have you ruled out radar/doppler/whatever the police use?

Comment: GPS FTW FTW FTW

Comment: @RogerRowland you can integrate acceleration and once again the resulting speed

Comment: @NeinDochOah In theory maybe, in practice you'll very quickly get a build-up of errors. [See here](http://www.chrobotics.com/library/accel-position-velocity) for one explanation.

Comment: Roger, a vehicle in motion, travelling at a constant speed, is always still accelerating to counter deceleration caused by friction and wind resistance etc.

Comment: @ProfK If it's travelling at a constant speed then by definition it's not accelerating. Maybe read the link in my previous comment to get an idea how feasible this would be with an accelerometer.

Comment: @user44635 Yes, I'm starting to think GPS, do the GPS units measure speed, or must you aggregate all vectors moved in a certain time?

Comment: By lay definition only. It still has a small measure of acceleration even at constant speed, check your high school science textbook. But you are correct that small measure of acceleration might not even register on a non-NASA type accelerometer, so it definitely won't be feasible.

Comment: @RogerRowland Apologies. You are correct about acceleration; I think I was confusing it with force require or something.

Comment: @ProfK That's ok, no offence. Maybe *you* should have checked that high school science textbook ;-)

Comment: @RogerRowland Even when I used it 28 years ago it was out of date. Can't find it, nope, won't read it.

Comment: @ProfK Borrow mine - it's 10 years older than yours but I'm sure Newton's laws of Motion are still the same ....

Comment: @ProfK Even a car sitting still on the earth's surface (at the equator) will experience about 0.034 m/s² acceleration due to the earth's rotation. Less as you approach the poles. That is a detectable amount, not with a cheap smartphone accelerometer but with a good accelerometer.

Comment: Almost any hand held GPS and most smartphones will give you GPS accuracy to usually better than 1 km/h often averaged over a few seconds for human displays so not instant response. This does not require installation.  There are test boxes for car enthusiasts that will do this.

Answer (score 2):

A wireless bicycle speedometer offers the features you require.

Commercial vehicle test systems use a bicycle wheel bracketed to the rear of the vehicle.

[image]

*Figure 1. [PEGASEM 5th wheel for vehicle testing](http://www.pegasem.com/english/products_uk/fwl_uk.htm).*

Figure 1 shows such a device.

The units are digital and as accurate as the wheel circumference data that you enter - typically 1 mm on a 2 m circumference (26" wheel).

Comment: Nice, and accurate, but I'm trying for a small unit someone can just place in the centre console or something.

Comment: OK, but if you're trying to use the car wheels then true circumference measurement will be the problem. I reckon that car speedo calibration will depend on tyre pressure.

Comment: Can you edit your original post to include some more description of what you're trying to achieve and what the intended use is? Is it one point calibration or several? What speed range? Test track or open road?

Comment: In the method shown in the answer, the car wheels have absolutely nothing to do with it. That's why the extra wheel is there, because it's a highly standardised wheel.

Comment: @ProfK: I'm confused by your last comment. I suggested the fifth wheel because its circumference can be accurately measured / calculated. My first comment is just stating the obvious that the car wheels can't be trusted as the circumference changes dynamically.

Comment: Yes, my bad. When I saw your comment about the car wheels, I hadn't see it was in fact you that posted about the fifth wheel. I am sorry for not reading everything more carefully.

Comment: I've done that kind of mix-up too. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

The accelerometer and GPS approaches can be done with a standard smartphone. As can a third approach: ask the car.

Almost all 'modern' cars have an OBDII diagnostic port. Often this is accessable from the passenger compartment. You can buy an OBDII-to-Bluetooth or RS232 adaptor for $10. This lets you query the car's engine management system for all sorts of information. However, this is probably going to be from the same driveshaft rotation sensor as the speedometer and therefore just as dependent on the assumptions about the size of the tyres.

I believe some of the DARPA Challenge vehicles used optical odometry, the same technique (and possibly the same chips) as in an optical mouse. Take a series of images of the road and infer distance between frames from there.

Comment: I would add to this that, if you used [structured light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_light) under the car then you could also account for suspension play (without needing stereo vision or rangefinders or something similar), which could affect measurements. A structured light emitter and camera in the same box could be put on any car; the structured light would give distance from the box to the ground and the (clocked) image sequence could give speed and direction.

Comment: The cars answer may be approximate, optimistic, unaware of wheel diameters or suffer rounding errors, while the information is usually avaiable in all new cars with OBDII or similar it cannot offer more accuracy that the dashboard display in practice.

Comment: I realise they can be done with a smartphone, or by other ways, but my interest in hobby electronics has just awakened, after some 20 years dormancy.